# android emulator ranchu vnc missing

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-sdk-tools

Using the newer android sdks, how can we enable vnc for headless emulators? My use case is jenkins instrumentation/connected test running.

For example:

```
export ANDROID_PACKAGE="system-images;android-25;google_apis;armeabi-v7a"
echo "no" | avdmanager create avd -f -k $ANDROID_PACKAGE -n test -b google_apis/armeabi-v7a
emulator64-arm -avd test -noaudio -no-window -ranchu -gpu off -verbose
```

There used to be a `-vnc :0` argument for qemu, but I am unsure about the  interplay between qemu and ranchu as it relates to vnc.